# jQuery shadowbox video not working in IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, shadowbox

The shadowbox video plugin is not working in IE7 although it works fine in Firefox and Safari.

Any comments would be really appreciated.

Site:

http://www.carolinedawes.com.au/update/abc-gardening-australia.html

HTML:

```
<a href="m/abc-gardening-australia-caroline-dawes.mov" rel="shadowbox;height=272;width=480">
<img src="i/abc-gardening-australia-caroline-dawes-gardening-adelaide.jpg" alt="caroline dawes" />
</a>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Shadowbox.init({
    players:    ["qt"]
});
</script>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in FF either.

Comment: I have it working in FF 3.5.3 & Safari 4.0.3 on a Mac

Comment: FF 3.5 on XP I get the following error: "Uncaught exception: Unkown player: html".

Comment: According to http://www.shadowbox-js.com/usage.html - quicktime video is called by 'players: ["qt"]'

Comment: works for me : ff 3.5.3, ie 7 and 8 on XP

Comment: Thanks zac and Marius. The error message I get in IE7 is "Exception thrown and not caught" on Line 2 Character 13882.

Comment: Its still not working...

Comment: I'm getting a 404 on that link.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a very old question but from what it seems like you might be having a problem with IE's `Dom:ready` event order which Voyta answers quite nicely here: [Shadowbox not working in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779618/shadowbox-not-working-in-ie#answer-2779941)

Hope this helps anyone else who's having this problem.